# How to display list of names present in viewdata in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewdata

I have a list of names in viewdata, but am not able to display it in view page

```
<body>

    <%= ViewData["names"].ToString() %>
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to provide more details if you want a good answer. It's a list of names, but what type is it (a string[], a List<string>, a string...)? If it's an array or a list, you'll have to iterate the object in order to write all the names. What's currently being displayed on the page?

Comment: I assume `ViewData["names"]` is a `List<String>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's a list of strings, you have to iterate through it like so (I've put a `div` there just to illustrate):

```
<% foreach (var name in (List<String>)ViewData["names"]) { %>
   <div><%= name %></div>
<% } %>
```

You also must make sure that `ViewData["names"]` is not null.